# app crashing when building a notification

Tags: android, notifications

i have written a music player for myself. Like all good players i want it to have a notification with a few controls. I don't remember where i copied most of the code for building such a notification from, but it worked on my old phone(Android 5). On my new phone(Android 6) however, it crashes at the line `builder.setPublicVersion(notification);`. As u can saee below i already tried replacing the deprecated `setContent`. But same result. It doesn't even throw anything, it just crashes.(I tried `try{...}catch(Throwable e){...}`).

i build the notification like this:

```
void buildNotification(boolean pausing) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My Player");

    int[] ids = new int[] {
            R.id.imgbtn_pause,
            R.id.imgbtn_next,
            R.id.imgbtn_delete};


    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification_layout);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        intent.setAction(String.valueOf(i));
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(ids[i],pi);
    }

    //builder.setContent(notificationView);
    builder.setCustomContentView(notificationView);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    builder.setPublicVersion(notification);
    if(pausing) notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_pause,R.mipmap.start);
    else notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_pause,R.mipmap.pause);
    notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.filename, currentFile);
    manager.notify(5,builder.build());
}
```

LogCat shows

```
07-14 22:17:26.967 21992-21992/com.example.ginso.myplayer A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7ff606e000 in tid 21992 (e.ginso.myplayer)

                                                             [ 07-14 22:17:26.968   458:  458 W/         ]
                                                             debuggerd: handling request: pid=21992 uid=10233 gid=10233 tid=21992
```

Comment: Please post the error you get from your logcat.

Comment: Thanks - could you include the part just below what you posted that includes the backtrace?

Comment: there is nothing after that